# Two symbols in an energy spectral density formula

Tags: calculus

Can someone please explain the meaning of two symbols in this formula,

1. the x with the caret (it probably means "vector", and I'll be embarrassed)
2. the equal sign, right in front of the integral, with a arrow head over it, pointing upwards.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8eRe.png
   Thank you.

Comment: (1) Fourier transform of $x$. (2) Definition, probably.